# How to send array contain dictionary to server using AFNetworking 2.0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, afnetworking-2

i am trying to use HTTP POST operation using AFNetworking 2.0 but i am getting error from my webservice.

My POST code

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    NSDictionary *parameters =myDictionary;
        [manager POST:[NSString getNewURLAsString:url] parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

            NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:AssignedToUserNotificationEvent object:dict];



        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];
```

Now my input myDictionary looks like this

```
{
    request =     {
        "assigned_by" = user1;
        "assigned_to" = "User 3";
        "assignment_remarks" = test;
        code = 01;
    };
}
```

Error Log

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad gateway (502)" UserInfo=0x7fa9ddf05660 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa9dde91190 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html", com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fa9dd9b3fb0>
```

> Update :

Finally able to solve the problem using `AFHTTPSessionManager`

Answer (score 1):

You should set content-type to application/json.

Comment: Proper content type for JSON is application/json.